# get next two words from a string in R

Tags: r

I want to get the next two words after finding a patters of words. 
Eg :tp_functional_location <- c("apple", "orange)

```
df <- as.data.frame(c("This is an apple and I love apples","I am going to buy orange but I can buy kiwis as well"))
names(df)[1]<-'title'

tp_pattern <- c("apple","orange")

pattern_fl <- paste0('(?<=', tp_pattern, '\\s)\\w+', collapse = "|")

df$new_word <- str_extract(df$title, pattern_fl)
```

I got the next word but I would like to get next two words .
Expected output is :
and I 
but I

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, using `str_extract`from package `stringr`:

```
str_extract(df$title, ("(?<=apple |orange )\\b\\w+\\b\\s\\b\\w+\\b"))

[1] "and I" "but I"
```

Explanation:

`(?<=apple |orange )` if you see `apple`or `orange` each followed by whitespace on the left ...

`\\b\\w+\\b\\s\\b\\w+\\b` ... match the next two words (identified by the word boundaries `\\b`)

Answer (score 1):

You could create the pattern in this way :

```
pattern_fl <- paste0("(?<=(",paste0(tp_pattern, collapse = "|"), ")\\s)\\w+\\s\\w+")
stringr::str_extract(df$title, pattern_fl)

#[1] "and I" "but I"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also create the pattern with `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
pattern_fl <- str_c("(?<=(",str_c(tp_pattern, collapse = "|"), ")\\s)\\w+\\s\\w+")
stringr::str_extract(df$title, pattern_fl)
```